# merge multiply objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, csv, database

I am converting a big database ( a csv file ) to mongodb ( it has like 117000 objects ) ,there are multiply records that have same IDs. I need to merge that objects to unique object.

For example what I have :

```
{ ID : "1" , number1 : "1" }
{ ID : "1" , number2 : "2" }
{ ID : "1" , number3 : "3" }
```

And I want to convert it to :

```
{ ID : "1" ,number1 : "1" ,number2 : "2" ,number3 : "3" }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you know the field names you want to merge into the object, or are they totally dynamic?

Comment: are you getting an array of these objects or its a complete string? It would help in solving your problem.

Comment: I don't know the name of field, they can be more than 500 different names.

Comment: They are all strings.

Comment: The data looks like the output of the map step of a map-reduce function. If this is your initial data, then run a map-reduce on this where the map just returns every document as is and the reduce step combines all documents with a single id into one.

Comment: Couldn't you use [`db.collection.update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) with upsert option?  If it's the first time saving it will create, otherwise update with the other field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though information is less, still I am proposing a solution for this. I hope it would help you. I have used RegEx, so column name won't be any issue(I hope so).

[RegEx-Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lR2gD0/1)

[Working-Demo-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfWCy/6/)

**Assumption**:

1. you know no of columns and they are fixed throughout.
2. Reading a file is not an issue, I have complete string in a single variable.
3. You know - column name of `primaykey`

**sample Data**

```
{ ID : 1 , number1 : "11" }
{ ID : 1 , number2 : "12" }
{ ID : 1 , number3 : "13" }
{ ID : 2 , number1 : "21" }
{ ID : 2 , number2 : "22" }
{ ID : 3 , number3 : "33" }
{ ID : 3 , number1 : "31" }
{ ID : 3 , number2 : "32" }
{ ID : 3 , number3 : "33" }
{ ID : 3 , number1 : "31" }
{ ID : 4 , number2 : "42" }
{ ID : 4 , number3 : "43" }
```

**Code - Please check comments in code**

```
var str = $('#regex_string').val();
//extract all valid Strings - Columns and their value
var extractValidString = str.match(/[\w\d]+(?=[,\s]?)/g)

//table - columns as Name, Age, Address in this case
//noOfCols will be 3
var noOfCols = 2
//Name of primary key's column    
var _pkID = "ID"

var hash = {};
while(extractValidString.length>0) {
    var row = extractValidString.splice(0,noOfCols*2);
    var indexPk = '';
    var newRow = true;
    for(var i=0;i<row.length; i=i+2) {
        //why i and i+1?
        //i is columns name and i+1 is value of that column
        if(hash[row[i] + ":" + row[i+1]] == undefined && _pkID == row[i]) {
            indexPk = row[i+1];
            hash[row[i] + ":" + row[i+1]] = {};
            hash[row[i] + ":" + row[i+1]][row[i]]=row[i+1];
        } else if(hash[row[i] + ":" + row[i+1]] && newRow) {
            indexPk = row[i+1];
        } else {
            hash[_pkID + ":" + indexPk][row[i]]=row[i+1];
        }
        newRow = false;
    }
}
console.log(hash);

//output
Object {ID:1: Object, ID:2: Object, ID:3: Object, ID:4: Object}
    ID:1: Object
        ID: "1"
        number1: "11"
        number2: "12"
        number3: "13"
    ID:2: Object
        ID: "2"
        number1: "21"
        number2: "22"
    ID:3: Object
        ID: "3"
        number1: "31"
        number2: "32"
        number3: "33"
    ID:4: Object
        ID: "4"
        number2: "42"
        number3: "43"
```